# Django POST requests from Postman forbidden after HEROKU DEPLOYMENT

Tags: django, heroku, postman, http-status-code-403, heroku-postgres

I uploaded my Django REST Framwork project to Heroku after following the steps carefully.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFFtDLZnbSs&t=193s&ab_channel=DennisIvy

In my project, I used BEARER tokens with jwt.

My database is PostgreSQL which is provided by Heroku.

It worked perfect while working locally but after deployment, I couldn't send requests through Postman.

Any ideas?

```
2022-06-04T16:36:50.456061+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/login" host=roy-messenger.herokuapp.com request_id=******-****-****-****-********** fwd="**.***.***.**" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=46ms status=403 bytes=3660 protocol=https
2022-06-04T16:36:50.458497+00:00 app[web.1]: Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.): /api/login
2022-06-04T16:36:50.459018+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.10.154 - - [04/Jun/2022:16:36:50 +0000] "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 403 3372 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0"
```

.

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for my project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['roy-messenger.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['roy-messenger.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'messenger_api',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'abra.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'abra.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '***************',
        'USER': '***************',
        'PASSWORD': '******************************************************',
        'HOST': 'ec2-52-48-159-67.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    # 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    #         'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    #     ]
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
del DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS']['sslmode']

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]
```